# Get name checkbox those checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have HTML code:

```
<!-- Bid estate type. - -->
<table style="display: table;" id="bid">

        <tbody><tr>
            <td>
                <input name="Văn bản chấp thuận cho thuê đất của Cơ quan chức năng nhà nước" value="13" id="checkox_13" type="checkbox">


            </td>
            <td>
                <label for="doc-bid">
                    Văn bản chấp thuận cho thuê đất của Cơ quan chức năng nhà nước

                </label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a class="button inline-button file-doc-link">Tải</a>
                <input name="file-doc-bid" type="file">
                <input name="id" value="13" type="hidden">
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>
                <input name="Văn bản thông tin về kế hoạch cho thuê Lô đất của cơ quan chức năng nhà nước" value="14" id="checkox_14" type="checkbox">


            </td>
            <td>
                <label for="doc-bid">
                    Văn bản thông tin về kế hoạch cho thuê Lô đất của cơ quan chức năng nhà nước

                </label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a class="button inline-button file-doc-link">Tải</a>
                <input name="file-doc-bid" type="file">
                <input name="id" value="14" type="hidden">
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>
                <input name="Văn bản thông tin quy hoạch của Lô đất" value="15" id="checkox_15" type="checkbox">


            </td>
            <td>
                <label for="doc-bid">
                    Văn bản thông tin quy hoạch của Lô đất

                </label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a class="button inline-button file-doc-link">Tải</a>
                <input name="file-doc-bid" type="file">
                <input name="id" value="15" type="hidden">
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>
                <input name="Hồ sơ mốc giới Lô đất" value="16" id="checkox_16" type="checkbox">


            </td>
            <td>
                <label for="doc-bid">
                    Hồ sơ mốc giới Lô đất

                </label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a class="button inline-button file-doc-link">Tải</a>
                <input name="file-doc-bid" type="file">
                <input name="id" value="16" type="hidden">
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>
                <input name="Trích đo địa chính Lô đất" value="17" id="checkox_17" type="checkbox">


            </td>
            <td>
                <label for="doc-bid">
                    Trích đo địa chính Lô đất

                </label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a class="button inline-button file-doc-link">Tải</a>
                <input name="file-doc-bid" type="file">
                <input name="id" value="17" type="hidden">
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>
                <input name="Chưa có thông tin pháp lý" value="18" id="checkox_18" type="checkbox">


            </td>
            <td>
                <label for="doc-bid">
                    Chưa có thông tin pháp lý

                </label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a class="button inline-button file-doc-link">Tải</a>
                <input name="file-doc-bid" type="file">
                <input name="id" value="18" type="hidden">
            </td>
        </tr>

</tbody></table>
<!-- Lease estate -->
<table style="display: none;" id="lease">

        <tbody><tr>
            <td>
                <input name="Giấy chứng nhận quyền sử dụng đất, sở hữu công trình gắn liền với đất" value="19" id="checkox_19" type="checkbox">
            </td>
            <td>
                <label for="doc-lease">
                    Giấy chứng nhận quyền sử dụng đất, sở hữu công trình gắn liền với đất
                </label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a class="button inline-button file-doc-link">Tải</a>
                <input name="file-doc-lease" type="file">
                <input name="id" value="19" type="hidden">
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>
                <input name="Giấy phép xây dựng" value="20" id="checkox_20" type="checkbox">
            </td>
            <td>
                <label for="doc-lease">
                    Giấy phép xây dựng
                </label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a class="button inline-button file-doc-link">Tải</a>
                <input name="file-doc-lease" type="file">
                <input name="id" value="20" type="hidden">
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>
                <input name="Bản vẽ thiết kế công trình trên đất" value="21" id="checkox_21" type="checkbox">
            </td>
            <td>
                <label for="doc-lease">
                    Bản vẽ thiết kế công trình trên đất
                </label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a class="button inline-button file-doc-link">Tải</a>
                <input name="file-doc-lease" type="file">
                <input name="id" value="21" type="hidden">
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>
                <input name="Bản vẽ hoàn công Công trình" value="22" id="checkox_22" type="checkbox">
            </td>
            <td>
                <label for="doc-lease">
                    Bản vẽ hoàn công Công trình
                </label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a class="button inline-button file-doc-link">Tải</a>
                <input name="file-doc-lease" type="file">
                <input name="id" value="22" type="hidden">
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>
                <input name="Giấy phép PCCC" value="23" id="checkox_23" type="checkbox">
            </td>
            <td>
                <label for="doc-lease">
                    Giấy phép PCCC
                </label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a class="button inline-button file-doc-link">Tải</a>
                <input name="file-doc-lease" type="file">
                <input name="id" value="23" type="hidden">
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>
                <input name="Quyết định cho thuê đất" value="24" id="checkox_24" type="checkbox">
            </td>
            <td>
                <label for="doc-lease">
                    Quyết định cho thuê đất
                </label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a class="button inline-button file-doc-link">Tải</a>
                <input name="file-doc-lease" type="file">
                <input name="id" value="24" type="hidden">
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>
                <input name="Hợp đồng thuê đất" value="25" id="checkox_25" type="checkbox">
            </td>
            <td>
                <label for="doc-lease">
                    Hợp đồng thuê đất
                </label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a class="button inline-button file-doc-link">Tải</a>
                <input name="file-doc-lease" type="file">
                <input name="id" value="25" type="hidden">
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>
                <input name="Quyết định phê duyệt đơn giá cho thuê đất đang áp dụng cho Lô đất" value="26" id="checkox_26" type="checkbox">
            </td>
            <td>
                <label for="doc-lease">
                    Quyết định phê duyệt đơn giá cho thuê đất đang áp dụng cho Lô đất
                </label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a class="button inline-button file-doc-link">Tải</a>
                <input name="file-doc-lease" type="file">
                <input name="id" value="26" type="hidden">
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>
                <input name="Hồ sơ mốc giới Lô đất" value="27" id="checkox_27" type="checkbox">
            </td>
            <td>
                <label for="doc-lease">
                    Hồ sơ mốc giới Lô đất
                </label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a class="button inline-button file-doc-link">Tải</a>
                <input name="file-doc-lease" type="file">
                <input name="id" value="27" type="hidden">
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>
                <input name="Trích đo địa chính Lô đất" value="28" id="checkox_28" type="checkbox">
            </td>
            <td>
                <label for="doc-lease">
                    Trích đo địa chính Lô đất
                </label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a class="button inline-button file-doc-link">Tải</a>
                <input name="file-doc-lease" type="file">
                <input name="id" value="28" type="hidden">
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>
                <input name="Chưa có thông tin pháp lý" value="29" id="checkox_29" type="checkbox">
            </td>
            <td>
                <label for="doc-lease">
                    Chưa có thông tin pháp lý
                </label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a class="button inline-button file-doc-link">Tải</a>
                <input name="file-doc-lease" type="file">
                <input name="id" value="29" type="hidden">
            </td>
        </tr>

</tbody></table>
<!-- Transfer estate. -->
<table style="display: none;" id="transfer">

        <tbody><tr>
            <td>
                <input name="Thông báo đấu giá" value="1" id="checkox_1" type="checkbox">
            </td>
            <td>
                <label for="doc-transfer">
                    Thông báo đấu giá
                </label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a class="button inline-button file-doc-link">Tải</a>
                <input name="file-doc-transfer" type="file">
                <input name="id" value="1" type="hidden">
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>
                <input name="Quy chế đấu giá" value="2" id="checkox_2" type="checkbox">
            </td>
            <td>
                <label for="doc-transfer">
                    Quy chế đấu giá
                </label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a class="button inline-button file-doc-link">Tải</a>
                <input name="file-doc-transfer" type="file">
                <input name="id" value="2" type="hidden">
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>
                <input name="Giấy CNQSD đất, quyền sở hữu Công trình gắn liền với đất" value="3" id="checkox_3" type="checkbox">
            </td>
            <td>
                <label for="doc-transfer">
                    Giấy CNQSD đất, quyền sở hữu Công trình gắn liền với đất
                </label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a class="button inline-button file-doc-link">Tải</a>
                <input name="file-doc-transfer" type="file">
                <input name="id" value="3" type="hidden">
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>
                <input name="Giấy phép xây dựng" value="4" id="checkox_4" type="checkbox">
            </td>
            <td>
                <label for="doc-transfer">
                    Giấy phép xây dựng
                </label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a class="button inline-button file-doc-link">Tải</a>
                <input name="file-doc-transfer" type="file">
                <input name="id" value="4" type="hidden">
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>
                <input name="Bản vẽ thiết kế công trình trên đất" value="5" id="checkox_5" type="checkbox">
            </td>
            <td>
                <label for="doc-transfer">
                    Bản vẽ thiết kế công trình trên đất
                </label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a class="button inline-button file-doc-link">Tải</a>
                <input name="file-doc-transfer" type="file">
                <input name="id" value="5" type="hidden">
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>
                <input name="Bản vẽ hoàn công Công trình" value="6" id="checkox_6" type="checkbox">
            </td>
            <td>
                <label for="doc-transfer">
                    Bản vẽ hoàn công Công trình
                </label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a class="button inline-button file-doc-link">Tải</a>
                <input name="file-doc-transfer" type="file">
                <input name="id" value="6" type="hidden">
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>
                <input name="Hợp đồng thuê đất (nếu là đất thuê)" value="7" id="checkox_7" type="checkbox">
            </td>
            <td>
                <label for="doc-transfer">
                    Hợp đồng thuê đất (nếu là đất thuê)
                </label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a class="button inline-button file-doc-link">Tải</a>
                <input name="file-doc-transfer" type="file">
                <input name="id" value="7" type="hidden">
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>
                <input name="Quyết định phê duyệt đơn giá cho thuê đất đang áp dụng cho Lô đất" value="8" id="checkox_8" type="checkbox">
            </td>
            <td>
                <label for="doc-transfer">
                    Quyết định phê duyệt đơn giá cho thuê đất đang áp dụng cho Lô đất
                </label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a class="button inline-button file-doc-link">Tải</a>
                <input name="file-doc-transfer" type="file">
                <input name="id" value="8" type="hidden">
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>
                <input name="Hồ sơ mốc giới lô đất" value="9" id="checkox_9" type="checkbox">
            </td>
            <td>
                <label for="doc-transfer">
                    Hồ sơ mốc giới lô đất
                </label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a class="button inline-button file-doc-link">Tải</a>
                <input name="file-doc-transfer" type="file">
                <input name="id" value="9" type="hidden">
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>
                <input name="Trích đo địa chính lô đất" value="10" id="checkox_10" type="checkbox">
            </td>
            <td>
                <label for="doc-transfer">
                    Trích đo địa chính lô đất
                </label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a class="button inline-button file-doc-link">Tải</a>
                <input name="file-doc-transfer" type="file">
                <input name="id" value="10" type="hidden">
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>
                <input name="Văn bản khác liên quan đến Lô đất và Công trình gắn liền với đất" value="11" id="checkox_11" type="checkbox">
            </td>
            <td>
                <label for="doc-transfer">
                    Văn bản khác liên quan đến Lô đất và Công trình gắn liền với đất
                </label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a class="button inline-button file-doc-link">Tải</a>
                <input name="file-doc-transfer" type="file">
                <input name="id" value="11" type="hidden">
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>
                <input name="Chưa có thông tin pháp lý" value="12" id="checkox_12" type="checkbox">
            </td>
            <td>
                <label for="doc-transfer">
                    Chưa có thông tin pháp lý
                </label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a class="button inline-button file-doc-link">Tải</a>
                <input name="file-doc-transfer" type="file">
                <input name="id" value="12" type="hidden">
            </td>
        </tr>

</tbody></table>
```

**I need display confirm screen before user press `Submit` button:**

```
<span id="checkbox_1Confirm"></span>
<span id="checkbox_2Confirm"></span>
....
<span id="checkbox_nConfirm"></span>
```

I try something like this (use jQuery):

```
if($("#checkbox_1").checked) {
    $("#checkboxConfirm_1").text($("#checkbox_1").attr("name").val());
}
```

but It doesn't work. I also try a loop, and only display checkbox checked, but not successful.

Comment: What do you want to display? The value of the `name` attribute or the `value` of the checkbox itself?

Comment: I need get `name` from **checked** checkbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**attr()**](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) functions as a *getter/setter*. When you call `attr()` with one parameter, it will get the value of the passed attribute.

Calling `val()` will only get you the value of the `value` attribute specifically which is not what you are looking for.

Finally, `checked` is not a valid property to use with jQuery. Use [**is()**](http://api.jquery.com/is/) and [**:checked**](https://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) instead

```
if($("#checkbox_1").is(":checked")) {
    $("#checkboxConfirm_1").text($("#checkbox_1").attr("name"));
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but I test, like this: https://gist.github.com/donhuvy/31307f77f19e14ead5ce#file-test-html  It doesn't work.

Comment: @dovy, sorry, there was a syntax error. See my updated answer and it working here https://jsfiddle.net/ammarcse/cxw26pzb/

Comment: In my case, no **`checked`** attribute. `checked` status received from user action. I try something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/879qq67x/ but not work. Please help me!

Comment: You had some syntax errors. If you open the console,(`F12`) you can see them. It is fixed here https://jsfiddle.net/ammarcse/879qq67x/1/

Comment: As you see, when I uncheck the checkbox, `bla_bla` still display. It is bug. Please help me!

Comment: @dovy, it is not a bug, you did not say you want that. https://jsfiddle.net/ammarcse/879qq67x/2/

Comment: Can you help me go to next step: loop all element those has id start with **id = `checkbox_`** , then display to all `<span>` tag those start with **id = `checkboxConfirm_`**

Comment: @dovy, I advise you give it a shot yourself first and then, if you face trouble,  ask a new question